# Join a list of mixed types with quotes wrapped only around strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list with mixed object types (strings and ints), and what I want to do is .join that list into a string where each string is wrapped in quotes BESIDES the integers. So for example if I had this list:

```
sample_list = ['abcd', 'chicken', 'wasd', 1, 'blah', 3, 'foo', 'bar']
```

I would like to produce the following string from it:

```
sample_string = "('abcd', 'chicken', 'wasd', 1, 'blah', 3, 'foo', 'bar')"
```

This is what I have:

```
sample_string = "(" + ', '.join("'{0}'".format(item) for item in sample_list if type(item) is not int) + ")"
```

Clearly my code is wrong because my integer values end up being dropped due to the *'if'* statement, but I've gotten stuck figuring out an elegant way to produce the string I desire, and was wondering if anyone could help with providing some tips on how to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
str(tuple(sample_list))
```

Returns:

```
"('abcd', 'chicken', 'wasd', 1, 'blah', 3, 'foo', 'bar')"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `"(" + ", ".join(map(repr, sample_list)) + ")"`. Note that this will use different quotes depending on what is in the string, but this could be desirable. To fix the code in your question, you could use the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator), instead of with if as a condition for the comprehension.